# Alias to SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have developer edition from SQL Server 2008, but now I have a piece of software with a hardcoded connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=sa;Password=1234;
```

Now I tried adding an Alias in the configuration tool to SQLEXPRESS, but it just doesn't want to use this new alias.

I enabled TCP/IP and restarted the service.

Comment: Do you know what type of application it is?  Is it a .NET application in which case you have an app.config or web.config file?

Comment: Hardcoding the connection string (including username and password)?
**WHY** do people keep doing such awful things?!?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Follow these steps to add an alias:

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Expand SQL Native Client Configuration
3. Right-click Aliases and select `New Alias...`
4. On the New Alias window:

   - Enter `.\SQLEXPRESS` for the Alias Name.
   - Select the appropriate protocol (e.g., Named Pipes)
   - Enter `.` for the server name (that's equivalent to `localhost`).
5. Click on OK to make the change.

Changing the HOSTS file to include a setting for SQLEXPRESS will only redirect DNS lookups for a machine called SQLEXPRESS to the specified IP address. That will not cause `.\SQLEXPRESS` to resolve to the localhost SQL instance.

Comment: Great answer! I was just about to start using explicit port numbers and so on when I happened upon this answer. This solved my problems perfectly. Thank you! :)

Comment: If you are using 64-bit Windows you might need to create the alias in both the 32-bit and 64-bit SQL Native Client Configuration.

Comment: I found my issue was with trying to use TCP, changing the alias to use named pipes made it work.

Comment: If it helps anybody else, I had to use the following Pipe Name for the `.\SQLEXPRESS` alias to work with my named dev instance: `\\.\pipe\MSSQL$STOLLEDEV\sql\query`

Comment: In addition to the above advice I also added localhost\SQLEXPRESS as an alias gets treated explicitly. I also added both aliases to both my 32bit and 64bit configuration just for belt and braces.